# How do you get the id values after running an aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql

given a comment table that looks like

```
| id | post_id | reply_count
| 1  | 1       | 10
| 2  | 2       | 5
| 3  | 1       | 20
```

I'm trying to return the comments, with its id, with the most reply counts, so I'd like the query to return rows with id 2 and 3.

```
| id | post_id | reply_count
| 2  | 2       | 5
| 3  | 1       | 20
```

If I try running

```
SELECT id, max(reply_count) as reply_count, post_id
From Comment
GROUP BY post_id
```

I get `SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column`.  I understand that this is because multiple ids can be returned if multiple post_ids have the same reply_count, but is there a way to have it just return the min(id) in these cases?

I've seen the suggestion to change the sql mode and I'm wondering if there's a way to get the results I'm after without doing that

mysql version: 8.0.25

Comment: what do you want if two rows have the same reply_count?

Comment: in this case I don't care which row is returned that's why I'm wondering if I can do something like min(id) at this point

Comment: in eshirvana's answer below, you would do `partition by post_id order by reply_count desc, id desc` then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in mysql 8 and above :

```
select * from (
   select * , row_number() over (partition by post_id order by reply_count desc) rn
   from tablename
) t where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I don't know much about this type of query, are there any performance consideration I should be aware of?

Comment: This query is using window functions and window function might cause performance issue but having an index on postid and reply count column should keep the query performant enough